# AngularJS : call promise method in factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have a angular factory in the following way , but when i try to call *getDepositAccountDetailsService* i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: this.getDepositAccountDetails.getDepositAccountDetailsService is not a function
```

How to call the promise inside factory.

```
  tellApp.factory('TabsFactory', function($resource){
    var activetabs = {};
    activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails = function(){
            $resource('XXXXXXX/:number', {}, {      
              getDepositAccountDetailsService: { method: 'GET', isArray: false}
            });
        }
    activetabs.setAccountInfo = function(accountnumber, result) {       
        var accountinit = {               
                accountInfo:[]                  
            };

      if(result.code == "s") {       
         this.getDepositAccountDetails.getDepositAccountDetailsService({number : accountnumber}).$promise.then(function(response){
                 return accountinit.accountInfo = response;

        }, function(error) {

        });
      }     
    }
    return activetabs;
  });
```

### controller

```
$scope.accountInfo = TabsFactory.setAccountInfo(accountnumber, $scope.result);
```

Comment: `activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails` should return `$resource` object & instead of `this.getDepositAccountDetails` you should do `activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails`

Comment: I have returned the $resource, but still the same issue

Comment: did you followed my second thing which i mentioned..or now you add `var activetabs = this;` instead of `var activetabs = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed couple of things in your code,

1. return $resource from service method `getDepositAccountDetails`
2. `this.getDepositAccountDetails` should be `activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails()` because you created a var for factory context.

**Factory**

```
tellApp.factory('TabsFactory', function($resource) {
    var activetabs = {};
    activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails = function() {
        return $resource('XXXXXXX/:number', {}, {
            getDepositAccountDetailsService: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }
    activetabs.setAccountInfo = function(accountnumber, result) {
        var accountinit = {
            accountInfo: []
        };

        if (result.code == "s") {
            activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails().getDepositAccountDetailsService({
                number: accountnumber
            }).$promise.then(function(response) {
                return accountinit.accountInfo = response;

            }, function(error) {

            });
        }
    }
    return activetabs;
});
```

Comment: sorry pankaj..still i am getting the same issue

Comment: TypeError: activetabs.getDepositAccountDetails.getDepositAccountDetailsService is not a function